# Userinput from Python will not be transferred to SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server

I hope you guys can help me. I'm setting up a login database, where users enter their information, and the information will be transferred to a SQL Server database.

My connection between Python and SQL Server is working, but I cannot figure out how to make the user inputs from Python into a variable that is transferable to the SQL Server table. Right now where it says 'Peter Hansen', my user input should be instead. Any suggestions regarding optimization and so on are welcome as well. I'm quite new to Python, so treat me thereafter :)

```
import pyodbc

Name = input('What is your name?')

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={SQL Server};'
    'Server=DESKTOP-H10O5O1\SQLEXPRESS;'
    'Database=Logins;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.LoginTable')

cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO dbo.LoginTable (Name)
                VALUES ('Peter Hansen')
                ''')
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I ended up going in a slightly different direction, which works for my needs:

```
import pyodbc

Name = input('What is your name?')
Username = input('What is your username?')
Password = input('What is your password?')

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={SQL Server};'
    'Server=DESKTOP-H10O5O1\SQLEXPRESS;'
    'Database=Logins;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.LoginTable (Name, Username, Password) VALUES(?,?,?)", Name, Username, Password)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO dbo.LoginTable (Name)
            VALUES
            ( ? )
            ''', (Name, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using python 3.5 and newer:

```
cursor.execute(f'''
            INSERT INTO dbo.LoginTable (Name)
            VALUES
            ('{Name}')
            ''')
```

Comment: This is directly concatenating user input to SQL syntax. This is bad practice as the user input is not treated as a literal but as syntax which limits the usable character set for the user input and constitutes a security problem as it allows for SQL Injection Attacks.